# EMR write to s3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have a spark job and interested in writing some program variables into s3 as a text file while running. I'm looking to write some strings, not dataframes.
Is there a proper way to perform it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the EMR developer guide ?

Comment: yes but unfortunatly I couldn't find any reference to this issue.

Comment: if you're using Spark in EMR then you'll be doing something like this: http://www.sparktutorials.net/reading-and-writing-s3-data-with-apache-spark /// but to truly help you, you need to show us what your code looks like and what you've tried. otherwise we cannot help you